Is there issue to connect metal chassis to Earth ground with resistor in between
I would like to know if it is safe to connect metal chassis to earth ground with 1Mohm resistor in between or this was causing issue for ESD.  The reason I am doing this is to reduce coupling noise by increasing the impedance.
Below image show how the system is wired

Below is conducted Emison with 1Mohm resistor between chassis and earth

With earth directly connected to chassis

Parts:
AC DC convertor: RAC10E-05SK/277
DC boost Regulator: TLV61046ADBVT 1.05Mhz
DC boost regulator isolated: RI3-0515S 40Khz
Buck regulator: TPS629203DRLR 2.5Mhz

There is not enough info to answer anything else than "no" as you have mains wiring and circuitry inside a non-earthed metal case. If you want some solutions to your problem, describe the problem and what the circuitry looks like.

@Justme I have added more info please let me know what else you need

The schematics and components used. You might have a noisy power supply used right, or quiet power supply used wrong. Like those Recom supplies needing a filter.

On the "With earth directly connected to chassis" picture there iare no units shown on the X axis. Is that picture using the same scale as the "Below is conducted Emison with 1Mohm resistor between chassis and earth" picture?

@Justme: I have talked to recom and the do not any filtering as long as there is no connection between analog ground and Earth ground

@Shahreza Recom datasheet of the power supply model you mentioned in the previous question but not in this one says it needs filter for EMI. And this is the first time you mention analog ground. We are not mind readers and don't know what details you are leaving out as you don't give enough details to even determine what details to request from your device.

@ChesterGillon Unfortunately, I do not have any right now, but I will update picture on Monday. Spike is around 500Khz

@justme I apologies if I am not providing all the information you need, since I do not want to overwhelm with unnecessary information, so please let me know if you need any additional information.

If you replace the resistor by an inductor, say 50 µH, you would retain the safety properties. Did you try that?

@Jens No I have not try that yet, but I will add picture test on Monday replacing resistor with inductor.

Not sure I'm following. You have AC voltage inside the enclosure so what about the safety ground? The normal procure would be to connect that directly to chassis and that has nothing to do with EMC but safety. How can you justify not having a safety ground?

Also what's the Y axis unit in those graphs? dBm? dBuV/m? Something else?

@Ludin The Y axis unit is dBuV

Is everything inside the box Class II (double insulated)?

@winny Regarding Class II probably not, so I do not need earth to connect to chassis.

You can have a Class II part within an otherwise Class I product. Last time I did, I ended up with a choke between earth and chassis ground for EMC reasons. CE approval came with a fault test of 25 A though the earth so the choke had to be oversized due to it.

If it is dBuV/m then it is ringing like Notre Dame. A lot of it looks like 50/60Hz harmonics. So regardless of what to place between chassis and earth, you need to look into the line filtering.

@Lundin Thanks, I added Y capacitor or line filter and fix the issue.

The chassis should usually* have a low resistance connection to ground to protect the user in case a live conductor contacts the chassis. A large resistor inline defeats this important protection.
For things like ESD wrist straps, a large resistor is inserted to limit current through the user should they come in contact with an energized conductor. This is not applicable here.
*May not be applicable with additional layers of insulation but it doesn't sound like that's the case here.

Thanks for the answer. So, if adding resistor is defeat the protection, what is your best suggestion to lower the coupling noise.  especially when you have multiple cable inside the chassis.

I am unsure what noise you are referring to when you say "coupling noise". What is the characteristic of the noise? Its frequencies and strength? How much attenuation is desired? What signals is it interfering with?

@vir OP's previous question was similar, about not passing EMI tests. I can't find it now, maybe deleted.

Yes, I try to ask better question. When I connect chassis to earth ground without any resistor, I have spike around 500Khz with 57db.  Any attenuation of 10 or 15db is sufficient.

Thanks for everyone feedback, however I was able to solve the problem by adding x Film capacitor (890324023025) between AC Neutral and earth.
Thanks to @justme comment I changed the X cap due to safety to Y cap and result is very similar. Also tried DD12.1121.111 which have filter with Y cap had the same result.
Below is the result


That might solve the problem of passing EMC, not safety. I hope the device is not used in a 230VAC country with non-polarized plug, where it would couple the Live to Earthed chassis via 150nF. Deadly if someone plugs it into un-earthed mains socket.

@justme That is a very good point, I will replace it with y capacitor and see if that will work.

I think you need a proper solution. A mains filter. You can just buy those. Both ones with and without an earth connection.

@justme I have already purchased an AC input filter such
DD12.9321.111 and had no effect on the result

The DD12.9321.111 is a version which has no capacitors between earth and live/neutral, so that's why it had no effect. I don't know if you want a filter for line/neutral only for some reason, but on the other hand you are now putting a capacitor between neutral and earth so maybe you do want a different mains filter.

In general (there are always exceptions), you want to bond the chassis to earth ground (or structure if earth ground is not relevant) through any means that provides a resistance of less than a couple of milliohms.
The "any means" in the above could be a direct mount of one unit to structure (or earth), or something like a bonding strap.
This serves two purposes.  First, it provides a low resistance path to ground in the even of an accidental short to the chassis by the hot such as 120 VAC, and thus performs a safety function.
Second, for high speed systems, this completes the shield around the electronics, and in this case serves an EMC purpose.
The one place I have seen high value resistors used is between signal grounds (or returns) and a chassis.  But this needs to be looked at on a case by case basis.

My Recommendations
$$10W 5V ~ 80 kHz$$ 1. A front-end CM filter is required to raise Zcm to grid and attenuate Vdm to & from grid. .
2. The common ground should be Vreturn = "0V"  to be used for all interfaces and metal enclosure and not the PE gnd.
3. A 1 Meg resistor is suitable from PE gnd to Vret to control ESD discharge current limit.


thanks for the answer. I Agree that we need all 3 points for PELV installation however based on manual we should not need any external component to pass class B as it stated on description " class B compliance without the need of any external components."

But your app. has dynamic Buck Boost loads which are the cause of your emission.
